# Como hacer un execute con un argumento tipo OUT INTEGER

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

Estoy trabajando en un login, cree este procedure que me ayuda a saber si el usuario existe por lo que la sentencia es que si es 1 pasa al menú y si es 0 no.

```
--PROCEDURE PARA LOGIN
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LOGIN 
(
    EMAIL IN VARCHAR,
    NUMERO_DE_DOCUMENTO IN INT,
    RESULTADO OUT INTEGER
)
AS
BEGIN
    Select count(*) INTO RESULTADO from LA_USUARIO where USU_EMAIL = EMAIL AND USU_NUMERO_DE_DOCUMENTO = NUMERO_DE_DOCUMENTO ;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RESULTADO);
END;
```

El siguiente execute tiene los datos para para que devuelva uno pero me da error ya que no tiene el numero de argumentos necesarios (PLS-00306).

```
EXECUTE DELETE_DETALLE_DOCUMENTO('KJULISA@Coutlook.es',1928763276487);
```

ya he probado de las siguientes maneras y todas dan error, no se si alguien sabe como podria hacer ese execute ?

```
EXECUTE DELETE_DETALLE_DOCUMENTO('KJULISA@Coutlook.es',1928763276487,);
EXECUTE DELETE_DETALLE_DOCUMENTO('KJULISA@Coutlook.es',1928763276487, NULL);
EXECUTE DELETE_DETALLE_DOCUMENTO('KJULISA@Coutlook.es',1928763276487,'');
EXECUTE DELETE_DETALLE_DOCUMENTO('KJULISA@Coutlook.es',1928763276487,1);
EXECUTE DELETE_DETALLE_DOCUMENTO('KJULISA@Coutlook.es',1928763276487,0);
EXECUTE DELETE_DETALLE_DOCUMENTO('KJULISA@Coutlook.es',1928763276487);
```